# Simple anonymous Azure web app gives 401.2 Access is denied

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-webapps

It's been five years since I just touched Azure so I am not very familiar with the latest settings.

I have just published a simple ASP.NET MVC app that I want to give anonymous access. Almost every setting is at its default value. I published it directly from Visual Studio 2017 selecting the Azure web app from the publishing tool. But I got:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Access is denied.
>
> Description: An error occurred while accessing the resources required to serve this request. The server may not be configured for access to the requested URL.
>
> Error message 401.2.: Unauthorized: Logon failed due to server configuration.  Verify that you have permission to view this directory or page based on the credentials you supplied and the authentication methods enabled on the Web server.  Contact the Web server's administrator for additional assistance.
>
> Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.7.3163.0

Who or what does not have access to which resource?

The bin\whatever.dll should be running as `hostingstart.html` is ignored.

At Azure under Authentication/Authorization, it says "Anonymous access is enabled on the App Service app. Users will not be prompted for login."

Comment: Can you also post your web.config and i am assuming it is working fine in local?

Comment: Thanks. That was a good hint. I found that there was a `<authorization>
      <deny users="?" />
    </authorization>` created by VS when i selected Windows authentication.  Removing it solved the problem!

Comment: Yes , that should resolve your problem.